# How can I prevent this Color Shift on Image Resize?

Tags: image, imageresizer

I am having a problem with a certain image color shifting when resizing with ImageResizer

http://khovexternalstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sitefinityexternalstoraage/images/default-source/external/nj/77-hudson/1.3-community-thumbnail-images/77-hudson_jersey-city_nj_exterior1.jpg

When resizing the image the bright blue sky, becomes dark and dreary looking. I don't notice this shift on all images, but it is obvious on this sample.

http://khovimagedemo.cloudapp.net/azure/sitefinityexternalstoraage/images/default-source/external/nj/77-hudson/1.3-community-thumbnail-images/77-hudson_jersey-city_nj_exterior1.jpg?width=450

http://khovimagedemo.cloudapp.net/azure/sitefinityexternalstoraage/images/default-source/external/nj/77-hudson/1.3-community-thumbnail-images/77-hudson_jersey-city_nj_exterior1.jpg?width=800

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your source image uses the `U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2` ICC profile, which is a target for print and not for screen use. 

It appears to be possible to copy the profile when using imageresizer, but you need to provide more details about which pipeline you are using and where this image will be used so that people can better assist you. A quick fix might be to update the source image to use sRGB, which is often the assumed default for most display devices / browsers.

Comment: I am currently using the ImageResizer Essentials Free Edition (GDI+ Pipeline) but would be open to changing that to overcome this issue. Converting the source image to sRGB first does work, though I suspect there are likely a number of these images through our CMS.

Comment: It should be noted that the original image doesn't render the same in all browsers. On Mac Safari, the original large image is rendered with the same unsaturated colors as your resized images (screenshot: http://imgur.com/Crux3P3). I suspect that not every app/tool knows what the `U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2` profile is and they end up defaulting to a basic color profile when interpreting or displaying the image. If converting the original to sRGB solves the problem, you may want to consider running that conversion on any image in your CMS with a non-standard color profile.